# How to keep child window always on top of its parent on mac os

Tags: macos, qt, window

As the title says, I found difference between windows and mac os.On windows, the child window is always on top of its parent like this `QWidget *child = new QWidget(parent);`. But the difference on mac os, when I clicked the parent window, it raise to the top, and it cover the child window.
So, I want to keep the child window always on top of the parent window, and the effect like windows.
I have tried to set the child windowflag to "**Qt::tool**","**Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint**",but it's not I wanted. It prevents me from clicking other windows or dialogs.
Forgive my poor English.Thanks.

Comment: you can try changing the flags, there is demo project in Qt Creator so you can do it easily otherwise sources available here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html

Comment: @basslo I had see the demo,  and try many window flag to my child window but no effect. In my case, I have three window, background window, videolayer window, mainwindow. And I set the mainwindow's parent is videolayer, the videolayer's parent is background. But the three window is alone, e.g. while I click the minimizeButton, the three window be hided one by one, but it is like one window on windows, that is what I want.

Comment: thanks a lot. I found my three windows' type is QMainWindow, and every QMainWindow is independent window on mac os so that the parent window can be top of child window, but the child QMainWindow is always on top of the parent QMainWindow on windows, I want do the same thing  on mac os like windows.What should I do? @basslo

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have any Mac device, Windows and linux only. I will try to see if i can find anything in documentation about that.

Comment: Thanks again.@basslo

Comment: so Qt::Tool didn't work! Because it is what you need (from documentation :  "If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it")  are you setting your mainWindow as the parent?

Comment: I have tried Qt::Tool, and it always keep mainWindow on the top. but the videolayer and background window break the order sometimes. And If I click the other application, and the window is under mainWindow, but top of videolayer and background, it makes me couldn't see my video.         And the same question, there are three window while I click the minimizeButton, I want keep the order of the three windows.And just one window while I click the minimizeButton.@basslo